# how to capture an incoming file upload and forward the request to another node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I have a node.js server running that accepts incoming requests that often has files attached. What I want to do is take these request, and without processing the file in any way, forward the request with the file to another node.js server where the actual file processing will be done.

I am having trouble figuring out how to forward the request with the file without having to download or manipulate the file on my machine.

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: This sounds like something you should do before the request even hits the NodeJS app. Probably something a load balancer, nginx or apache would do.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. It looks like it will solve my problem.